# KQL CloudAppEvents: view when some mutes you on teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, kql, azure-sentinel, microsoft365-defender

What log can I check on defender or sentinel to see when a meeting particpant has muted another user?

```
CloudAppEvents
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30d)
// | where Application == "Microsoft Teams"
| mv-expand parse_json(RawEventData)
| evaluate bag_unpack(RawEventData,  OutputColumnPrefix='Entities_')
```

This is what i checked, but cannot find the right action type or operation? is there documentation for action types or operations?

Answer (score 0):

Given the context provided, it appears that there isn't a dedicated log or operation within Microsoft Defender or Sentinel that explicitly records when a meeting participant mutes another user in Microsoft Teams. While the CloudAppEvents log can be utilized to track activities within Teams, it doesn't offer granular details regarding muting actions specifically.

Ref.

[Search the audit log for events in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/audit-teams-audit-log-events#use-defender-for-cloud-apps-to-set-activity-policies)

[Microsoft Sentinel integration (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-cloud-apps/siem-sentinel#alerts-and-discovery-logs-in-microsoft-sentinel)